# Publishing Gradle to Maven generates invalid pom with '+' sign in dependencies

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a Gradle project that declares dependencies like

```
dependencies {
    compile group:'jaxen', name:'jaxen', version:'1.+'
}
```

However whenever I publish with either the old Maven upload plugin or the new maven-publish plugin it generates this in its POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
  <version>1.+</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Which when a different Maven project tries to depend on the Gradle project fails with:

```
Could not resolve dependenices for project ...: Failure to find jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.+
```

I've been searching for a few hours and can't figure out how to get Gradle to declare Maven-valid dependencies. Does anyone know how to do this automatically? Is this a gradle bug?

I'm using the latest Gradle 2.3, Maven 3.3.1, and Java 8

Comment: This is an open [bug](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3224). By chance I remembered seeing this reported on the gradle forums.